# Xcode UI Testing Processes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm new to UI Testing and am struggling to find any documentation. Could anyone explain the relationship between the different processes that are running while conducting UI testing? From what I have researched, there is one process running the target application, and another running the test code. How do the two interact?

Answer (score 0):

The process running the test code has access only to the UI hierarchy of the target application (unless you're doing sneaky signal passing) and cannot access or modify the data or app logic. The UI hierarchy is called using titles, labels, accessibilityIdentifiers, or accessibilityLabels somewhat interchangeably with a CSS-like selector syntax.

For documentation, there isn't really any of substance from Apple; I'd recommend taking a look at Joe Masilotti's "UI Testing in XCode 7": http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-xcode-7/

Comment: Got it, thank you! I've read through that; very good source. I am still a bit confused about the different processes running. So one process is fired to run the actual UI Test code, and another to run the actual application? What is the reasoning for running multiple processes?

Comment: Preventing you from accessing or modifying data or app logic, so that you're forced to only use the UI hierarchy (aka, what's available to the user), as far as I know. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave comments, but a note for when you are UI testing your app, if you have environment variables you will need to pass the environment variables set for your test into your app instance. This one liner helped me out a lot.

```
app.launchEnvironment = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
```